# Prolog copy a specific letter from a list to another in the same place

Tags: list, prolog, character

so I'm trying to make a method in prolog that gets a character and 2 lists, in whatever place the character is found in list 1, I inject that character in the list 2. The method returns the new state of the list 2. It doesn't seem to work even if I find it correct. Here's my code.

```
transfer([],[],_,[])
transfer([H¦T],[_¦T1],C,R):-
    transfer(T,T1,C,R1),
    H==C,
    append([H],R1,R).
```

So if I executed ?- transfer([h,e,l,l,o],[0,0,0,0,0],e,X). I would get as result X=[0,e,0,0,0]. Any ideas?

Comment: A few ideas: (1) `[H,T]` and `[_,T1]` are lists consisting only of two elements. So your predicate cannot work with arguments other than empty lists or lists with 2 elements. You need to check your list syntax. (2) `append([H], R1, R)` can be replaced with `R = [H|R1]`. (3) You are using an anonymous variable `_` for a list element that you actually probably care about in the solution. So it should be a "don't care".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about what relation your predicate should describe. If the first two lists are empty, the last argument is also an empty list, no matter the comparison element. This is the base case you already have. Otherwise you have two mutually exclusive cases:

1. The head of the first list equals the comparison element. In this case the comparison element is in the result list.
2. The head of the first list is different from the comparison element. In this case the head of the second list is in the result list.

You can model this case distinction with the or-predicate `;`. Then transfer/4 might look something like that:

```
transfer([],[],_,[]).
transfer([H1|T1],[H2|T2],C,[R|Rs]):-
   ((H1=C,R=C);(dif(H1,C),R=H2)),     % case 1 or case 2
   transfer(T1,T2,C,Rs).              % the relation holds for the tails as well
```

With this definition your example query yields the desired result:

```
   ?- transfer([h,e,l,l,o],[0,0,0,0,0],e,X).
X = [0,e,0,0,0] ? ;
no
```

Alternatively you could also describe the case distinction above in a separate predicate and then use maplist/4 to apply the relation to the three lists:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

e_x_y_z(E,X,Y,Z) :-
   (X=E,Z=E);(dif(X,E),Z=Y).

transfer(L1,L2,C,R) :-
   maplist(e_x_y_z(C),L1,L2,R).
```

I find this version somewhat easier to read since the definition of the actual relation is separated from the recursion.  Note how the comparison element in e_x_y_z/4 is the first argument, so the predicate can be passed to maplist/4 lacking three arguments for the elements of the three lists respectively.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot